# Not able to detect back, refresh and close events in on (IOS) apple phone browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile, cross-browser

We already have code to detect back, refresh and close events in our web application.

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {          
        
        (e || window.event).returnValue = "";
        return "";
    });
```

We are displaying a save changes pop-up before the user clicks on back, refresh, or closes the browser. This is working perfectly fine in most of the web and mobile browsers except in the apple phone browser. How can we achieve the above functionality in the apple phone browser?

I have also tried the **pagehide** event for the apple phone browser, but it only detects the close event, not back and refresh. Also, the save changes pop-up is not displayed.

```
window.addEventListener("pagehide", function (e) {          
        
        (e || window.event).returnValue = "";
        return "";
    });
```

Any help is appreciated, or any other alternative solution would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yet another sub par implementation from Apple, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event  Apple appear to be deliberately trying to kill the Web, the app store indirectly was the worst thing to happen for web developers, if your targeting IOS.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about refresh. But for detecting back you can use this:

```js
window.history.pushState(null, "", window.location.href);
window.onpopstate = function() {
    //back button clicked
};
```